# Elsarticle: pagebreak before abstract

Tags: page-breaking, elsarticle

I am using the elsarticle template and according to the [preparation rules](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-parallel-and-distributed-computing/0743-7315/guide-for-authors#20000) the Abstract should be presented in page 2. Yet, the newpage is ignored. Any suggestion?

Note that the Abstract is part of the frontmatter.

Here it is the setup:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal of Parallel and Distributed Computing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title of the Paper {\Large (Regular Submission)}}

\author{Author 1}
\ead{author1@domain.com}
\author{Author 2}
\ead{author2@domain.com}
\address{Address}

\begin{abstract}

%% Text of abstract

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's possible to move this (the abstract) to the second page, but what goes with it? The horizontal rules and the keywords? And is there a page break after that so that the first section starts on page 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't bother, as they will probably use the LaTeX source for their typesetting. But if you really want to comply, here is a way:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal of Parallel and Distributed Computing}

%% Code added to comply with the requirement that the
%% abstract is on the second page together with the keywords.
%% Remove up to the <end of patch> line for removing the patch.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
 {\ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi}
 {\ifvoid\absbox\else\clearpage\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip30pt\fi}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
 {\hrule\vskip12pt}
 {}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}
 {\hrule\vskip12pt}
 {}
 {}{}
\appto{\pprintMaketitle}{\clearpage}
%% <end of patch>

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title of the Paper {\Large (Regular Submission)}}

\author{Author 1}
\ead{author1@domain.com}
\author{Author 2}
\ead{author2@domain.com}
\address{Address}

\begin{abstract}

Text of abstract

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

I've also removed the now useless horizontal rules and spaced out a bit more the keywords from the abstract.

Answer (score 3):

The `frontmatter` environment of [`elsarticle`](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class) merely sets the title at `\end{frontmatter}` as can be seen from [`elsarticle.cls`](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/file/0007/109357/elsarticle.cls):

```
\newenvironment{frontmatter}{}{\maketitle}
```

As such, if you're interested in modifying the layout, you need to just look at `\maketitle` and any subsidiary calls to macros. Under the `preprint` document option, `\maketitle` defaults to `\pprintMaketitle`:

```
\long\def\pprintMaketitle{\clearpage
  \iflongmktitle\if@twocolumn\let\columnwidth=\textwidth\fi\fi
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \printFirstPageNotes
  \begin{center}%
 \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
   \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    \hrule\vskip12pt%                                   <--- Horizontal rule
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi% <--- Insert abstract
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi% <--- Insert keywords
    \hrule\vskip12pt%                                   <--- Horizontal rule
    \end{center}%
  \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}%
  }
```

A patch to `\pprintMaketitle` can be used to insert breaks as needed:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% Update first horizontal rule to insert a \clearpage
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}% <cmd>
  {\hrule\vskip12pt}% <search>
  {\clearpage\hrule\vskip12\p@}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
% Update second horizontal rule to insert a \clearpage
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}% <cmd>
  {\hrule\vskip12pt}% <search>
  {\hrule\clearpage}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

`elsarticle` has the command `\newpageafter`. You can use `\newpageafter{author}` to add a pagebreak after the title page, before the abstract.

Comment: I tried putting `\newpageafter{author}` in several places, and the abstract still appears on the first page with emails and corresponding author note bleeding outside the frame. Same for all the above answers too, so maybe it's an issue specific to my document.